# Do not download the file complete

Tags: java, file, sockets, download

I try to download a file using socket not url.. with the following code the file is not 
completely downloaded and when I try to open the file it show 
the message that the selected file could not be open...  this error can be removed by using 
url.openconnection() methods but  it need to be done through socket.... need suggestion.

```
public class Check {

private String addres;



public void FileDownload(String urladd) {
    try {
        this.addres=urladd;



        String address;
        URL url_of_file=new URL(addres);
        String hostaddress=url_of_file.getHost();
        Socket mysocket=new Socket(hostaddress, 80);
        System.out.println("Socket opened to " + hostaddress + "\n");
        String file=url_of_file.getFile();
        System.out.println(" file = "+file);


        OutputStream os = mysocket.getOutputStream();

        os.write(("GET " + file + " HTTP/1.0\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.write(("HOST: " + hostaddress + "\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.write(("\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.flush();


       String url = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\file_downloaded.jpg";
       File f=new File(url);
       f.createNewFile();

        OutputStream ops = new FileOutputStream(f);

        byte data = 0;
        InputStream in=mysocket.getInputStream();



        data = (byte) in.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            ops.write(data);
            data = (byte) in.read();
        }
        ops.flush();
        ops.close();
        mysocket.close();
```

Comment: why do you need to do it through sockets instead of HttpURLConnection?

Comment: in short i want to download a file through a specific network interface... and with url i did not find any java code to download a file form a specific network interface( WiFi or Ethernet) of my system...but with socket i can create a socket and bind to a specific interface then send request and received data through that network interface...

Answer (score 0):

if you inspect your output file i suspect that you will find that it contains an HTTP response header in addition to the file data (since you are speaking the HTTP protocol).

Comment: @ArseIsonline - open the file in an editor/viewer of some sort.